# Prometheus how to sum the number of lable

Tags: prometheus

If I have a metric with the following labels:

```
my_metric{group="group a"}  100
my_metric{group="group b"}  100
my_metric{group="group c"}  100
next
my_metric{group="group a"}  100
my_metric{group="group b"}  50
```

how to sum lable not vaules and show in grafana ,i want to get 3 2 ...